# Kendo grid group datetime column only on date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-grid

I have a few datetime columns in Kendo grid in an ASP.NET MVC application. When grouped on any of them, the groups are segregated and displayed for same dates as they have different times.

I want to group them based on date only and ignore the time part. The column should still have the values in datetime format only.

I could display the group headers as Date only by using `.ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= kendo.toString(value, 'MM/dd/yyyy') #")` in the column definition.

Can something similar be applied while grouping?

Comment: Can you modify your model to return a calculated field?

Comment: If so you could return fields DateOnly and DateAndTime then define a column for DateOnly but use the client template to display DateAndTime.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63251311/how-can-i-format-the-kendo-grid-group-date/72403424#72403424