# How can i format the kendo grid group date

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using below grouping in Kendo Grid.

```
.Group(groups => groups.AddDescending(p => p.TransactionMonth))
```

The month is coming in an ISO format like 2020-03-02T00:00:00. The same is displaying in the group header. Is it possible to convert this to show in MMMM yyyy format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this. Added a GroupHeaderTemplate to the column bound as given below

```
columns.Bound(t => t.TransactionMonth).Title("Transaction Month").Hidden(true).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value.split('T')[0]), 'MMMM yyyy') #");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
columns.Bound(a => a.CreatedDate).ClientTemplate("#= CreatedDateTime ? kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(CreatedDateTime), 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') : '' #").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value.split('T')[0]), 'MM/dd/yyyy') #");
```

CreatedDate Should contain only Date part, CreatedDateTime Should contain Datetime